# Angular 2 firebase Authenticating using google provider

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am new on angular, and I am trying to make a user login component by Angularfire2.

I have 2 main files,

1.app.component.ts (The login button on this page).
2.user.service.ts (All user function in this file).

I tried to log a current user data by User.service.ts on the app component,but i get undefined.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service' 
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  userDetail:firebase.User;
  constructor(public user:UserService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.user.getUserDetails();
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.user.signInWithGmail();
  }

  onLogOut(){
    this.user.signOut();
    console.log("Logged Out!");
  }
}
```

**user.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  user:Observable<firebase.User>;
  userData: firebase.User;
  constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
    console.log(Math.random());
    this.user.subscribe((user)=>
      {
        if(user){
          this.userData = user;
          console.log(user.displayName);

        }
      }
    );
  }

  signInWithGmail(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  signOut(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
  getUserDetails(){
    console.log(this.userData);
  }
}
```

What is the problem here?
Thank you.

Comment: did your login works correctly?

Comment: @Hareesh yes, but I can not get the userData by the getUserDetails Funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Observables to return the data

```
getUserDetails(): Observable<any>{
    return this.afAuth.authState.map((auth) =>  {
        if(auth == null) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return auth;
       }
  });
}
```

In client side

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.user.getUserDetails().subscribe(user=>{
       console.log(user);
    });
}
```